No run django, Cannot install django
PS D:\aaa\WorkSpace_31\py\testDjango\test\hello> python manage.py runserver 8888
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\aaa\WorkSpace_31\py\testDjango\test\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aaa\WorkSpace_31\py\testDjango\test\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 144, in inner_run
    run(
  File "D:\aaa\WorkSpace_31\py\testDjango\test\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 270, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\aaa\WorkSpace_31\py\testDjango\test\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 77, in __init__       
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socketserver.py", line 457, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 795, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 19: invalid start byte


I have changed the computer name
I have switched to an older version
I have installed navicat, xampp, SQL Server Management Studio 19


In general, Django assumes that UTF-8 encoding is used for I/O. This may cause problems if your system is set to use a different encoding. Recent versions of Python allow setting the PYTHONUTF8 environment variable in order to force a UTF-8 encoding. Windows 10 also provides a system-wide setting by checking Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support in Language ‣ Administrative Language Settings ‣ Change system locale in system settings.
